# Mining one gas costly transaction yourself due to lowered gas limits

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, mining-pools, parity

Giving the current Ethereum [network circumstances with transaction spam](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/549p5a/the_network_gas_limit_is_currently_too_low_to/), a lot of miners have decreased their transaction upper gas limit. However this makes deploying some more complex contracts, like multisig wallets ([example](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol)), impossible.

If one would buy mining capacity from miners or Amazon EC2 high performance computation instances, how one could tell `geth` or `parity` to mine one particular transaction?

Comment: You actually couldn't mine a transaction that's over the network gas limit, even if you ran your own miner. The gas limit can only be raised or lowered by 1/1024 of the current limit each block. So to raise the gas limit you'd need to have 51% of the mining power

Comment: @TjadenHess: Thanks. I was not aware of the `1/1024` increments per each block and how it affects the network.

Comment: The multisig wallet has deployment gas cost of ~1.45M. The network block gas limit target recommended by Foundation blog post is 1.5M. I think the issue here is that due to deployment TX being near the upper limit of block limit and other TXs get into blocks too it doesn't get deployed.

Comment: Actually what happend is that they recommended 1M at first, but recently updated that to 1.5M in order to allow multisig wallets. The gas limit is currently at 1,024,533 and rising slowly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having your own miner can't help in this situation.

The *block* gas limit is set by the protocol, with the miners able to increase or decrease it by a small percentage every block. A transaction may not be processed if it (or the total transaction so far) goes over that limit, no matter who mines the block.